# Mix two meshes' positions to produce one (like a shapekey) and randomize the factor randomly per instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can make this:

[image]

But how can I duplicate these multiple times and randomize the opening and closing of the mouth per instance - If I put random-node to the mixRGB node's Factor, all the vertices get randomized, that's no good :/

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @alambre 's answer, I managed to do this what I was after:

[image]

Here are the nodes:

[image]

Comment: that's great and also looks cleaner... here's the mouth [animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0vfkmh6jnthhc6/shapekey_like_nodes2.blend?dl=1) thing I had haha

Comment: @alambre haha great! Yeah I can see some uses for that surely! :)

Comment: I admit, there's a couple of useless 'set position' nodes there :/ oh well...

Comment: no problem..! if you have many islands per objects you can try dividing the 'index' [by the number of islands](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mee1jfxpoid9lzz/shapekey_like_nodes1.blend?dl=1), then it should work...

Comment: @alambre iiinteresting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my try on it: instances are just clones so you will need to 'realize instances' to make them unique, I also recreated the shape key as an offset vector for each vertex and transfered that to the mesh... then used 'island index' to provide the ID values for 'random value' node... they look fun when animated :p

[image: node setup]

Modified .blend file:

[image]

[Dropbox mirror](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hpip1upvc9qczi/shapekey_like_nodes.blend?dl=1)

Comment: That is just excellent! Although I noticed it's not suited for what I'm after because of the 'seed' animation. BUT, you helped me to realize that Mesh Island node existed, which helped me to find a totally new solution, I shall post that here as well. We have very good applications here. Thank you so much! :)